# Nvidia Driver issues, and GCC version 10.2.0 unavailable

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, 20.04, gcc

Specs:
Quadro P1000 (compatible with driver version 440.100, attempting to get version 450.57)
kernel: 5.7.11-050711-generic
Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Key problem:
I've been unable to determine if I can actually get the newest gcc version on ubuntu 20.04. (currently have found 10.1 experimental), the newest I can seem to find is 9.3.0 (but newer versions are available on other platforms). currently I am unable to compile the drivers correctly (Nvidia's run scripts with dkms), and I am getting very nasty warning messages on startup and shutdown (they're long, and unrelated/unecessary if I can get this to work).

The installation script it advises me to check says that the driver was compiled with version 10.2.0. it seemed to me that I could not download (or at least couldn't find) the correct version for ubuntu, I thought I could downgrade, but got the same error message.

I currently have 9.3.0 and 10.1 installed, I'm somewhere between a beginner and an intermediate, but I've relied heavily on apt to obtain my packages, and am not sure (without a provided address for wget) how to install the package otherwise (at the time of writing, I am currently stuck with the command line).

I could force it to ignore the versions, but I'm already getting ACPI errors (unhandled region) and DC state mismatches, which suggests to me that I've done something very wrong, and I (hope) that this is it.

I know I'm almost certainly omitting necessary information, but I'll update it as necessary.

I'm aware that I can use apt to install the Nvidia drivers, but I have done so twice and had the second screen stop working, so I would like to use the Nvidia run file so that I don't have to deal with it again.

Comment: Where are you getting the Nvidia-450 driver from?  It is available from the graphics-drivers ppa, and that may avoid problems with drivers from other sources.

Comment: I've had issues with using that.. I actually downloaded the reccomended driver from the Nvidia website (they provide a bash script). 450 isn't available from the ppa repository (but 440 is).

Comment: As of 7/16/2020 450 is on the ppa, 450.57-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.2 See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263383/nvidia-driver-issues-and-gcc-version-10-2-0-unavailable?noredirect=1#comment2138183_1263383

Answer (score 0):

If you see *1 in my post it refers to notes that describe in further detail

1. You can get gcc10.2 from here
   https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/releases/gcc-10.2.0/
2. Save it to home
3. Enter terminal and untar the zipped folder; you will probably need to sudo
4. cd into the new folder; it should be called gcc-10.2.0

Enter these terminal commands in that folder

1. `contrib/download_prerequisites`
2. cd ~

Enter these terminal commands from home

1. `mkdir build && cd build`

==========================================================================

- Here you need to decide where you want it to install.  I will refer to /usr/local/bin because it's already in the PATH

2. `../gcc-10.2.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/bin/gcc-10.2.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-10.2`

==========================================================================

- Replace x with the number of cpu cores you have*1.  This will take a while depending on how fast your computer is.

3. `make -j x`

==========================================================================

- Once that all completes enter this command in the terminal which wont take long.

4. `sudo make install-strip`

==========================================================================

Now you must change the default gcc version so you are using the right version to install the NVIDIA driver.

1. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-10.2.0/bin/gcc-10.2 70 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/bin/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++-10.2`

- Replace my paths with wherever you installed it and remember to use the executable in the bin folder of the gcc-10.2.0 folder.

==========================================================================

- Enter this terminal command and choose gcc-10.2

2. `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

==========================================================================

- After that check your gcc version to clarify

3. `gcc --version`

- It should say 10.2

Where I got my information

- Building GCC 10 on Ubuntu Linux: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/
- Installing newer GCC versions in Ubuntu: https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu

*1. I changed this from the guide in the link who says: "you typically want to pass twice the number of your computer cores to the make command in order to speed up the build" I assume he is talking about threads in which case not all cpus have multithreading.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will this pose problems when I reboot the machine? If I build a kernel module with this version of the gcc, will I have to stick with that version (possibly causing errors if other parts are compiled with a lower version?

Comment: If you are meaning your nvidia driver, I downgraded succesfully to 440 with no problem.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I was concerned that changing my default gcc problem would case problems with the complication of other packages, though this may not be the case